# Playing with Iframes in Firefox addons

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I started to work with **Firefox addons**. I would like to create an addon for security purposes, that scans all **iframes** in the current page and replace the **SRC** attributes if needed ( **!** before loaded **!** ). How can I do that?

I know how to make a javascript, but how to refer the current document?

I don't know how to compose the script, that runs before every page load.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (frame in document.frames) {
    frame.src = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do in content script (cause as DOM becames available the loading of resources is already started).

But you can do it using request interception via [nsIContentPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentPolicy?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIContentPolicy).

There are [other ways to intercept requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Intercepting_Page_Loads).

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code in my Firefox addon to extract the HTML contents of iframes in a webpage

```
var url="http://www.hemantpawar.com/";    
var allFrame = content.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
       for(var n=0; allFrame[n]!= null; n++)
        {
            content.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[n].src= url;                
        }
```